# Igualar ponteiros em C

Tags: c, programação-estruturada

Nesse código que peguei pois nao estava conseguindo pensar no exercício, na linha 3 do código o programa pede o scanf do min, sendo que min é um ponteiro, e min recebe um valor do scanf, porem o valor do min nao seria o valor da endereço que o ponteiro indica? Nesse caso parece que o valor que min recebe é o mesmo de *min, nao consegui pegar o racicionio, se alguem puder clarear agradeço muito a atencao

O exercicio seria esse: Usando a estratégia acima, escrever uma função que retorne o valor mínimo e máximo
de uma sequência de n valores fornecidos pelo usuário. A leitura dos valores digitados
no teclado deve ser feita dentro da função. Contudo, a quantidade de valores a ser lido
(n) deve ser um parâmetro de entrada da função

```c
int minMaxSeq(int n, int *min, int *max) {
    int i, x;
    scanf("%d", min);
    *max = *min;
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (x > *max){
            *max = x;
        } else if (x < *min){
            *min  = x;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int n, minimo, maximo;
    scanf("%d", &n);
     if (minMaxSeq(n, &minimo, &maximo))
        printf("%4d%4d\n", minimo, maximo);
    else printf("sequencia vazia\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse código que "pegou" não está assim muito bom. E isso não te ajudou muito.
Esse título "igualar ponteiros em C" também não faz sentido, em especial se a gente imaginar que isso seja devido a essa linha

```
        *max = *min;
```

Talvez, já que está aparentemente aprendendo, devesse evitar o vício desse tipo de declaração do programa que "pegou":

```
        int minMaxSeq(int n, int *min, int *max) // ...
```

Está correto, muitos autores e empresas usam assim. No entanto está declarando o que na lista de argumentos? `n`, `min` e `max`. E o que é `n`? `int`. O que é `max`? `int*`, um ponteiro para int. E o que é `min`? outro ponteiro para `int`, `int*` te diria o compilador C. Então evite declarar coisas como `int    *max` e ao invés declare sempre  `int*    max` porque está declarando um nome e o nome é `max`. E declarando o tal nome como uma variável de um tipo, e o tipo é `int*`

#### De volta ao programa

Então `max` é `int*` e assim `*max` é o que? Um `int`, claro. E não se trata de igualar ponteiros. se foi isso que gerou o título. É apenas uma atribuição de um `int` a outro.

Essa função tem que RETORNAR esses dois valores, `min` e `max`. No entanto as funções só podem retornar um argumento, e assim a opção do autor nesse caso foi retornar os DOIS valores passando ponteiros para dois `int` como argumentos. Esses são **argumentos de saída**. O cara que chama `minMaxSeq()` passa os dois `int` para receber o resultado. Note que a função não tem um `return` e precisa ter, como seu compilador dee ter dito.

Esse trecho

```
    scanf("%d", min);
    *min = *max;
```

indica apenas a leitura em separado do primeiro número. Claro que ele pode ser o único valor se `n` for 1 e assim ele será o mínimo **e** máximo. E se não for o único aí o programa lê os valores restantes. Se o cara digitar 5 lê, claro, os outros 4, por exemplo.

Teste sempre o retorno de `scanf()`. É ingênuo seguir com o programa se `scanf()` não leu nada: é claro que vai perder a conta. Se ia digitar 10 valores e dá erro no segundo vai mesmo tentar ler outros 8 sabendo que o programa falhou? Não devia. Mas está escrito assim e é bobagem.

Para retornar mais de um valor se pode sempre retornar uma struct, assim:

```
typedef struct
{
    int min;
    int max;

}   Min_Max;

Min_Max*    min_max(unsigned n);
```

E seria o comum em C: retornar a struct ou um ponteiro para uma alocada dinamicamente. Algo assim

```
Min_Max*     min_max(unsigned n)
{   // exemplo
    int     res = 0;
    int     x = 0;
    Min_Max* p = (Min_Max*) malloc( sizeof(Min_Max) );
    if (p == NULL) return NULL;

    printf("Valor 1 de %u: ", n);
    res = scanf("%d", &p->min);
    if ( res != 1 ) return NULL;
    p->max = p->min; // afinal so tem um por enquanto
    for ( unsigned i = 1; i < n; i = i + 1)
    {
        printf("Valor %u de %u: ", 1+i, n );
        res = scanf("%d", &x);
        // se res != 1 entao deu errado tentando ler o i-esimo numero
        if ( res != 1 ) return NULL;
        if (x > p->max)
           p->max = x;
        else if (x < p->min)
            p->min = x;
    };  // for()
    return p; // retorna o ponteiro para a nova struct

};  // min_max()
```

Assim tem uma outra vantagem: pode mudar o conteúdo da `struct` sem mudar a declaração. Pode incluir por exemplo a média além do máximo e mínimo e não vai mudar o que se chama assinatura da função. E assim não precisa mexer nos programas antigos que usavam essa `struct`. É o conceito de encapsulamento. Na prática isso vai claro muito mais longe, mas fica o exemplo.
Como são apenas dois valores usar dois ponteiros é simples e mais econômico afinal ;)

### Usando uma função *factory*

Em geral se chamam *funções factory* funções que a cada vez que são chamadas retornam um ponteiro para uma nova unidade de algo, um registro, um buffer de transmissão, um personagem, algo. Nesse caso é só uma estrutura com os valores de `min` e `max`. Claro que como são só dois pode nem valer a pena, mas se fossem 5 acho que já se ia pensar nisso, certo?

E porque não um vetor? Porque nem sempre tudo o que quer retornar é do mesmo tipo: pode precisar retornar um nome, `char*`, um peso `float`, uma quantidade, `unsigned int`, e um preço, `float`, por exemplo, e não seria assim uma novidade.

E ao usar `typedef Coisa` e retornar um ponteiro para `Coisa` se pode sempre mudar o conteúdo sem mudar a assinatura da função, já que `Coisa` continua sendo `Coisa`.

Claro, as duas funções são similares e recortar e colar ajuda bem. Atente para a alocação via `malloc()` na segunda e para o fato de que deve destruir a estrutura quando ela não for mais ser usada, chamando `free()`.

**Nota:** há uma corrente, baseada em parte em textos de 20 anos atrás, que recomenda não usar *cast* para o ponteiro retornado por `malloc()` por determinadas razões. Antes de comentarem aqui que não se deve fazer isso vou dizer que *sempre* faço isso como um lembrete para eu mesmo saber que estou alocando o que acho que estou alocando. E também porque programo mais em C++ que em C e em C++ isso é obrigatório. Sim, não se aloca memória em C++ assim desde 2011 praticamente ;) ...

O programa de exemplo chama as duas funções e pode comparar o uso.

#### uma versão mais segura da função original

```
 int minMaxSeq(
    unsigned    n,
    int*        min,
    int*        max
    )
{
int     res = 0;

    printf("Valor 1 de %u: ", n);
    res = scanf("%d", min);
    if ( res != 1 ) return -1;
    *max = *min;
    n = n - 1; // ja leu um
    for ( unsigned i = 0, x; i < n; i = i + 1)
    {
        printf("Valor %u de %u: ", 2+i, 1+n );
        res = scanf("%d", &x);
        // se res != 1 entao deu errado tentando ler o i-esimo numero
        if ( res != 1 ) return -i-2;
        if (x > *max)
           *max = x;
        else if (x < *min)
            *min =x;
    };  // for()
    return 0;
}
```

Essa versão é um pouco mais legível, provavelmente. E mais segura. E tem uma interface melhor. A função retorna zero se leu ok, ou -x se deu erro ao tentar ler o x-esimo elemento. E tem a cortesia de instruir o infeliz sobre o que vai digitar, ao invés de deixar a tela preta lá...

#### O EXEMPLO com as duas funções

Abaixo uns exemplos de execução do código que está a seguir:

```
PS C:\src> gcc -o teste -Wall -std=c17 mm.c
PS C:\src> ./teste
Entre com o tamanho da sequencia: 4
Valor 1 de 4: 1
Valor 2 de 4: 2
Valor 3 de 4: 3
Valor 4 de 4: x
erro -4 na funcao
PS C:\src> ./teste
Entre com o tamanho da sequencia: 4
Valor 1 de 4: -34
Valor 2 de 4: 3
Valor 3 de 4: 345
Valor 4 de 4: -12
Dos 4 valores lidos pela funcao MIN = -34 e MAX = 345


Testando com a funcao "factory" e 3 elementos

Valor 1 de 3: 3
Valor 2 de 3: 2
Valor 3 de 3: 1
Dos 3 valores lidos pela funcao MIN = 1 e MAX = 3
PS C:\src>
```

#### um programa de teste

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct
{
    int min;
    int max;

}   Min_Max;

Min_Max*    min_max(unsigned n);
int         minMaxSeq(unsigned,int*,int*);


int main(void)
{

unsigned n = 0;
int     min = INT_MAX;
int     max = INT_MIN;
int     res = 0;

    printf("Entre com o tamanho da sequencia: ");
    res = scanf("%u", &n);
    if ( res != 1 ) return -1;

    res = minMaxSeq( n, &min, &max );
    if ( res < 0 )
    {
        printf( "erro %d na funcao\n", res );
        return -2;
    }
    printf("Dos %u valores lidos pela funcao MIN = %d e MAX = %d\n",
        n, min, max);

    printf("\n\nTestando com a funcao \"factory\" e 3 elementos\n\n");
    Min_Max* novo = min_max( 3 );
    if ( novo == NULL )
    {
        printf( "erro na funcao de leitura\n");
        return -2;
    }
    printf("Dos %u valores lidos pela funcao MIN = %d e MAX = %d\n",
        3, novo->min, novo->max);
    
    free(novo);

    return 0;

};  // main()


Min_Max*     min_max(unsigned n)
{   // exemplo
    int     res = 0;
    int     x = 0;
    Min_Max* p = (Min_Max*) malloc( sizeof(Min_Max) );
    if (p == NULL) return NULL;

    printf("Valor 1 de %u: ", n);
    res = scanf("%d", &p->min);
    if ( res != 1 ) return NULL;
    p->max = p->min; // afinal so tem um por enquanto
    for ( unsigned i = 1; i < n; i = i + 1)
    {
        printf("Valor %u de %u: ", 1+i, n );
        res = scanf("%d", &x);
        // se res != 1 entao deu errado tentando ler o i-esimo numero
        if ( res != 1 ) return NULL;
        if (x > p->max)
           p->max = x;
        else if (x < p->min)
            p->min = x;
    };  // for()
    return p; // retorna o ponteiro para a nova struct

};  // min_max()

int minMaxSeq(
    unsigned    n,
    int*        min,
    int*        max
    )
{
int     res = 0;
int     x = 0;

    printf("Valor 1 de %u: ", n);
    res = scanf("%d", min);
    if ( res != 1 ) return -1;
    *max = *min;
    n = n - 1; // ja leu um
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < n; i = i + 1)
    {
        printf("Valor %u de %u: ", 2+i, 1+n );
        res = scanf("%d", &x);
        // se res != 1 entao deu errado tentando ler o i-esimo numero
        if ( res != 1 ) return -i-2;
        if (x > *max)
           *max = x;
        else if (x < *min)
            *min =x;
    };  // for()
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bela aula arfneto, obrigado! Então só pra deixar claro, não há diferença entre int* ponteiro e int *ponteiro?

Comment: não, não há diferença. Mas está declarando `ponteiro` e o tipo de ponteiro é `int*` como o compilador e os livros vão te dizer. `*coisa` é o conteúdo do endereço `coisa`. asterisco é um operador, o inverso de &, pointer to E address of na literatura.

Comment: Ah entendi. Quando eu coloco scanf em um ponteiro como eu fiz no código, scanf("%d", min);..o valor atribuído então vai sempre para o conteúdo do endereço da variável? Nesse caso "mínimo"?

Comment: `scanf() ` não aloca memória. Então você precisa passar um endereço para cada especificador, que é aquilo como `%d ` ou ` %s ` por exemplo. Assim ou você passa um ponteiro, algo declarado como `tipo*`, ou passa o endereço de algo usando o inverso, `&algo`. Para cada especificador, E TESTE o retorno. É ingenuidade não testar. Veja o programa que te mostrei...

Comment: incluí um exemplo da função que aloca uma estrutura nova, assim pode ver a diferença entre passar dois ponteiros como parâmetro e retornar uma estrutura com os valores.

Answer (score 2):

Vou supor que você já conhece as notações:

- &variavel : endereço de memória da variável variavel
- *ponteiro : valor contido no endereço de memória apontado por ponteiro

A função **scanf** espera a partir do segundo parâmetro um endereço de memória.
Supondo-se que você tenha uma variável de tipo inteira chamada min, você usaria a função scanf desta forma:

```c
    int minimo;
    scanf("%d", &minimo);
```

No seu exemplo, considerando exclusivamente o código existente na função **minMaxSeq**, você tem **min** definida como um ponteiro de inteiro (**int ***). Como min já é um ponteiro de inteiro, você está usando a função scanf desta forma:

```c
    int* min = /*algum endereço de memória, por exemplo endereço da variável minimo */;
    scanf("%d", min);
```

Em linhas gerais o que o seu programa faz é:

- a função principal (main) aloca espaço para 3 variáveis inteiras;
- invoca a função **minMaxSeq** passando **n** por valor e **minimo** e **maximo** por referência (passa os endereços das variáveis);
- sua função **minMaxSeq** lê o primeiro valor e o atribui às variáveis apontadas por min e max (minimo e maximo) através do endereço das variáveis que foi recebido por parâmetro;
- nas iterações seguintes, os próximos valores são lidos e comparados com os valores atuais de min e max e, eventualmente, min ou max podem ser alterados;
- ao final da execução de **minMaxSeq**, o controle volta para main e os valores minimo e maximo podem ser utilizados para serem "impressos" para o usuário.

Comment: Alex obrigado pelo comentário! Só pra deixar claro, não há diferença entre int* ponteiro e int *ponteiro?